# Alternative to TK to get a fileOpen dialog (Spyder)

Tags: python, tkinter, spyder

I am a MATLAB user and trying to find something similar to uigetfile.

I am using Anaconda/Spyder to give the user a choice to select a file (through a dialog box). I tried a variety of solutions offered here, but the dialog box always is behind the Spyder (never focused). I also tried 'easygui', but the result is the same.

Any suggestions (below is the code)?

```
def getfile():
    import tkinter as Tkinter, tkinter.filedialog as tkFileDialog    
    root = Tkinter.Tk()
    #root.withdraw()
    #root.focus_force()
    file_path = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(parent=root,title='Pick a file')    
    #root.update()
    return file_path 

def getfile2():
    import easygui
    file_path = easygui.fileopenbox()
    return file_path
```

Comment: Just an idea, try adding `root.after(200, root.focus_force)` just before the `.askopenfilename(...)`

Comment: Thanks. This helped partially. I will answer my question below.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @TheLizzard, below is what works:

```
def getfile():
    import tkinter as Tkinter, tkinter.filedialog as tkFileDialog
    root = Tkinter.Tk()
    root.after(100, root.focus_force)
    root.after(200,root.withdraw)    
    file_path = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(parent=root,title='Pick a file')    
    return file_path
```